# Different character rendering http vs https

Tags: html, https, character-encoding

In a static HTML page (a long text page) if I view the page under http://example.com/my_page.html a few extraneous CP-1252 quotes (e.g. `“quotes”`) appear fine, but if viewed under https they are rendered as pure ASCII (e.g. `â€œquotesâ€` ).

This behavior is the same under both Chrome and Firefox.

So, the short term fix was to simple replace the quotes with `&ldquo;` but what causes this difference between http and https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string â€œquotesâ€ is not Ascii but UTF-8 encoded “quotes” misinterpreted as windows-1252 encoded. This is most probably caused by different `Content-Type` lines in HTTP headers: they specify different character encodings (or one of the headers does not specify encoding at all, forcing browsers to guess, and they guess wrong).

This is not related to HTTP vs HTTPS but to differences in HTTP headers. For a more detailed analysis, the HTTP headers would be needed.